# If Both Article Page and PDF File Have the Same Content, Will It Cause SEO Problems?

Tags: seo, googlebot, duplicate-content, pdf

I have a blog page and I publish articles on this blog page. You can download these articles as PDFs by clicking the download button on that article.

PDFs are the same content found in the article. The PDF is also indexed by google bots.

In this case, when the Google bot crawls the article page, it crawls both the PDF and the article. Is there any duplication problem because they are both the same content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, what Google shared as information 12 years ago is still valid.

> Q: Is it considered duplicate content if I have a copy of my pages in both HTML and PDF?
> A: Whenever possible, we recommend serving a single copy of your content. If this isn't possible, make sure you indicate your preferred version by, for example, including the preferred URL in your sitemap or by specifying the canonical version in the HTML or in the HTTP headers of the PDF resource. For more tips, read our Help Center article about canonicalization.

More information you could find here: [PDFs in Google search results](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2011/09/pdfs-in-google-search-results)